# Redirect file output to variable

Tags: python

Let's say I am working with a function from a third-party package that insists on writing its output to a file instead of making a return statement. Let's say I would actually prefer to prevent the function from writing and capture the output as a variable. Is that possible without changing the function itself?

Comment: Does it allow you to provide the filename?

Comment: Create a named pipe. Run the function in a thread, and give it the named pipe as the filename. Then read from the pipe in your main thread.